# Can I upload or edit files via SFTP on ec2 Instance built via Elastic Beanstalk?If yes then does it hamper the updated files when environment updates

Tags: laravel

I have deployed a laravel project through Elastic Beanstalk with RDS. Now I need to give access to some other user via SFTP for modification (Even i know this would not be a good practice but it's on staging env). Then changes made via ssh or uploaded through stays there or flushed when Beanstalk Environment gets updated.

Or we must upload files through Elastic Beanstalk portal only?

Comment: Do you want to modify source ( like .env) after deployment?

Comment: Not .env, but else if we need to update anything else like content or features.

Comment: No idea. Why don't you use git and use all git possibilities, then clone it to server?

Comment: That is the point to worry if i do things like that under beanstalk environment, will they effect on whole running project once due to xyz reasons beanstalk environment gets updated and old ec2 instance will get placed with newer one.